# Vectorize Scipy cubic interpolation for multiple Numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numpy-ufunc

I have a np.array of 50 elements. For example:

```py
data = np.array([9.22, 9. , 9.01, ..., 7.98, 6.77, 7.3 ])
```

For each element of the `data` np.array, I have a `x` and `y` data pair (both with the same length) that I want to interpolate with. For example:

```py
x = np.array([[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ],
              ...,
              [ 1.01, 2.01, 3.02, 4.03, 5.07 ]])
```

```py
y = np.array([[0. , 1. , 0.95, ..., 0.07, 0.06, 0.06],
              ...,
              [0. , 0.99 , 0.85, ..., 0.03, 0.05, 0.06]])
```

**I want to interpolate each data element with the respective np.array of `x` and `y`.**

I have the following solution using `map()`:

```py
def cubic_spline(i):
     return scipy.interpolate.splev(x=data[i],
                                    tck=scipy.interpolate.splrep(x[i], y[i], k=3))

list(map(cubic_spline, np.arange(len(data)))
```

**But I'm wondering if there is a way to do it directly with scipy and numpy to optimize the execution time**. Something like:

```py
scipy.interpolate.splev(x=data,
                        tck=scipy.interpolate.splrep(x, y, k=3))
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since the target Scipy functions does not support working on many arrays and there is apparently no functions to do that, I think the answer is no. In fact, even the [internal function called](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/de80faf9d3480b9dbb9b888568b64499e0e70c19/scipy/interpolate/_fitpack_impl.py#L524) does not support vectorization on several Bspline at the same time. At least, not using Scipy. You can use `fitpack` directly from Scipy but this is not standard (implementation defined and may change in the future) and calling it wrongly just cause the interpreter to crash (I tried).

Comment: Thanks @JérômeRichard for your answer. It is a pity that it can't be used for splines, because with linear interpolation (`spicy.interpolate.interp1d`) it is possible. I wll try Scipy's `fitpack` as you suggest. Thank you!

Comment: `fitpack` and/or `fitpack_impl` are certainly not something a user should touch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a single `x` array and multiple `y` arrays, newer interpolators (`make_interp_spline`, `PchipInterpolator` etc) support multidimensional `y` arrays automatically.

If you really have a collection of  pairs of 1D arrays, `x` and `y`, where `x` arrays differ, and you want scipy to loop over these datasets, then no, scipy does not support that. You'd need to loop over them manually.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @ev-br! I will explore the interpolators you commented. As you mention, in some specific cases I will be able to take advantage of the flexibility of the cubic interpolator, but in general I use the manual iteration with the `map()` function that I indicated in the question. Thanks!